# Find the numbers larger than them in the collection

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say we have a collection of numbers like { 16,17,4,3,5,2 }. Now the objective is to find those numbers which are greater than the rest in the collection while compare with their right elements.

Indicates that 16 compared to 17 is less and cannot be consider. While 17 compared to 4,3 5 and 2 is always greater and hence will be consider. Likewise, 4 though greater than 3 abut less than 5 will be discarded. But 5 compared to 2 is greater. And since 2 is the rightmost element will always be consider. I have written the below program to do so and it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var intCollection = new List<int>() { 16,17,4,3,5,2 };
            var discardedElements = new List<int>();

             for(int i=0;i< intCollection.Count;i++)
             {
                 for(int j=i+1;j< intCollection.Count; j++)
                 {
                     if (intCollection[i] < intCollection[j])
                     {
                         discardedElements.Add(intCollection[i]);
                     }
                 }
             }
             Console.WriteLine("Successful elements are");
             intCollection.Except(discardedElements).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}", i));
             Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Result

```
Successful elements are
17
5
2
```

But this program is not an optimized one. Any better algorithm for the same problem?

N.B.~ The program though apparently doesn't have any real time use but it will help in improving algorithm.

Comment: Optomize for memory usage, battery usage, cpu usage, multi core, distributed computing?  This might be a bit too broad.

Comment: If you're just trying to cut down on cpu cycles, store the result elements in a new array instead of the discarded.  Then in your 2nd for lop, you can short circuit as soon as you verify that the ith element is not valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go from right to left and filter increasing sequence of numbers

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( String[] args )
    {
        var intCollection = new List<Int32>() { 16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2 };
        var intResults = new List<Int32>();
        var currentMaxValue = Int32.MinValue;

        for ( Int32 i = intCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i )
        {
            if ( intCollection[ i ] > currentMaxValue )
            {
                currentMaxValue = intCollection[ i ];
                intResults.Insert( 0, intCollection[ i ] );
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "Successful elements are" );
        intResults.ForEach( i => Console.WriteLine( "{0}", i ) );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a name for that kind of algorithm?

Comment: I don't know it's name but I beleive it is very simple

Comment: Good **O(N)** algorithm, bad implementation which effectively turns it into **O(N^2)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> NumbersBiggerThanTheFollowingOnes(IList<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers.Count <= 0)
        yield break;

    int max = numbers[numbers.Count - 1];
    yield return max; // Last element is considered bigger than the "following" ones.

    for (int i = numbers.Count - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (numbers[i] <= max)
            continue;

        max = numbers[i];
        yield return max;
    }
}
```

Sample test code:

```
var intCollection = new List<int>() { 18, 10, 13, 16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", NumbersBiggerThanTheFollowingOnes(intCollection).Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate from the right to left, and keep the current maximum value then compare.

```
// Check empty intCollection
result.Add(intCollection[intCollection.Count-1]);
var currentMaxValue = intCollection[intCollection.Count-1];
for(int i = intCollection.Count - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (intCollection[i] > currentMaxValue) {
        result.Add(intCollection[i]);
        currentMaxValue = intCollection[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: While admittedly your code doesn't differ much from a C# version, why would you post a C++ answer to a C# question?

Comment: Sorry, just change to C#. I'm more comfortable with C++ than C#.